# How to access one key of JSON tree from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the value of 'caste' key from the JSON tree in Firebase Realtime Database.[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scjqX.png)

I have the user's unique ID and all my auth and user objects are in place. How do I get a reference to only the 'caste' key into a String variable?

Thanks,
[image: PS: full tree]

Comment: show me the full tree.. you can fetch caste using parent key

Comment: that is the full tree. I just added one user as of now for developing.

Answer (score 1):

```
  DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("project-android-536f3");

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                             String caste = (String) messageSnapshot.child("caste").getValue();
                            }
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi! caste is returning null in my case.

Comment: I've added an answer below

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I never provided the unique User ID so it never got data from the database.

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("caste");
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    caste = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });
```